# Prepopulated form input element doesn't accept first input when submit btn is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I have a form and a input element that gets a default value via `:value="something"`. I want the submit button for this form to be disabled if

1. The input's value is falsey
2. Or, the input's value is the same as the default value.

**My problem:**

When I first click on the input (and the submit btn is disabled) and type a single thing, the input element doesn't change visually but I can see in the console that its value changed and the submit button no longer becomes disabled.

It seems as if I can't change the value of the input unless this submit button isn't disabled. However, if I get rid of my `@input`, then I'm able to type into this input fine. So, my guess is that it's something wrong with my event handler.

I've been unable to find a post with my problem, it was also hard to think of what exactly to google since this problem is so strange to me.

When the input matches the old value, it correctly disables the button. When I backspace when the input is 'a' it produces 'apple'. Not sure what's happening there.

Minimal working example of my problem:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input :default-value="something" :value="something" @input="onInput"/>
            <button type="submit" :disabled="isDisabled">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "test",
    data () {
        return {
            something: "apple",
            isDisabled: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onInput (event) {
            console.log("Current value: " + event.target.value);
            console.log("Default value: " + event.target.getAttribute("default-value"));
            console.log("isDisabled: " + (event.target.value === event.target.getAttribute("default-value")));
            this.isDisabled = !event.target.value || (event.target.value === event.target.getAttribute("default-value"));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Vue SFC REPL: [https://vuep.run/2192b4fb](https://vuep.run/4c3978e4)

[image: Console when I type backspace->backspace->e into input]

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: use `keydown` as opposed to `input` maybe

Comment: keydown gets rid of the problem where the first typed key doesn't appear visually, but also seems to introduce its own problems.. When I fully remove 'apple' then type another backspace, the input value becomes 'appl' even though it should remain empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vue `computed` property and of course, use `v-model` rather `:value`

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: "test",
  data() {
    return {
      defaultVal: "apple",
      something: "apple",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return this.defaultVal === this.something;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput (event) {
      console.log("Current value: " + event.target.value);
      console.log("Default value: " + event.target.getAttribute("default-value"));
      console.log("isDisabled: " + (event.target.value === event.target.getAttribute("old-name")));
      
      // don't do this now
      // this.isDisabled = !event.target.value || (event.target.value === event.target.getAttribute("old-name"));
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input :default-value="defaultVal" v-model="something" @keyup="onInput"/>
    <button type="submit" :disabled="isDisabled">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```